# Azure DevOps Style Templates

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

Is there a way to copy or import/export settings in Azure DevOps between projects? The Process Templates are ridiculously limited. I would like to be able to copy stuff like Styling Rules, Custom Columns, default Areas or Teams, and not have to set up everything that is identical every time.

Of course every project is different and need adjustment, but something as basic as a default color coding should be possible.

Comment: There is, but for native Azure DevOps services, **there is NO**. See my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure DevOps designed such feature, but it only available in the organization that migrate from local TFS which turned on this feature.

See the official document:

[Hosted XML process model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/hosted-xml-process-model?view=azure-devops)

> Feature availability: The Hosted XML process model is only supported
> for organizations that have migrated to Azure DevOps using the data
> migration tool for Azure DevOps.

You can see that my organization can export and import the configuration:

[image]

Your idea make sense. If you need this feature on nature Azure DevOps services, I suggest you to create a feature request here:

[Azure DevOps User Voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest)

Microsoft DevOps product team plan their feature timeline based on the user voice of the above community.

And you can see the product roadmap of DevOps here:

[Azure DevOps Roadmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline)